# Using createServerComponentClient from supabase in NextJS when deployed to prd causes a 404

Tags: next.js, supabase

I have the page in NextJS-13: `/app/test/page.tsx` that simply shows Hello world. (deployed to vercel)
Within the `/test` directory I also have a `layout.tsx`.

Now when I use `createServerComponentClient` from `import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';` in it, i get a *404*. On my dev server (localhost) it works fine however (I see the page without a 404).

*layout.tsx*:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export default async function Layout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

When I remove `createServerComponentClient` it works (no 404).

I also have the `middleware.ts` as mentioned here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in my next.config I had this which breaks routing

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  }
```